# Matplotlib custom style default title location

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am building a custom style for matplotlib and would like to make the default title location left aligned, but have not figured out a way to do this with the matplotlibrc file. Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simple answer is "No".
The [matplotlib rc params](https://matplotlib.org/users/customizing.html) have no option to change the title's alignment.

You may use [the usual way of specifying the title's alignment](https://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/titles_demo.html) as

```
plt.title('Left Title', loc='left')
```

The addition the title location as rcParam is currently discussed on the [GitHub issue tracker](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/9682).